# how to delete a message not a channel discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have tried looking for how to delete a message by id and I get the id by getting the channel and going through the json object and take the last message id and want to delete it but when I run it just deletes the entire channel

This is what I have for the code

````
let x = client.channels.cache.get('830341462070919168')
let lastMessageID = x.lastMessageID;

client.channels.cache.get('830341462070919168').fetch(lastMessageID).then(msg => msg.delete());

client.channels.cache.get('830341462070919168').send('**UPDATE!!**\nList of Photo Shoots to be done\n```1. Nick\n2. Drew```');
````

And I saw on another form that I could try this

````
client.channels.cache.get('830341462070919168').fetch(lastMessageID).then(async msg => {
    await client.channels.cache.get('830341462070919168').send("**UPDATE!!**\nList of Photo Shoots to be done\n```1. Nick\n2. Drew```");
    if (msg) msg.delete();
});
````

And it does the same thing as what I have above

All I want it to do is just get the last message id and delete that message by the id and nothing else and then update with a new message that I will have loop through all the sign ups and then put that into a message

output:
UPDATE!!
Lise of Photo Shoots to be done

```
1. {name}
2. {name}
etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it all I needed to do was to put the id inside the delete function

Example:

```
client.channels.cache.get('830342527340773386').messages.delete(lastMessageID);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `client.channels.cache.get('830341462070919168').fetch(lastMessageID)` would return the channel itself. So calling `Channel.delete()` would delete the channel. So you can either do like what you have answered, or do `client.channels.cache.get('830341462070919168').message.fetch(lastMessageID)` to get the message and then resolve the promise to delete the message. [<MessageManager>#fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)